# CUDA: Creating object with G++ linker and cuda object files

Tags: c++, linker, g++, cuda

I compiled my normal cpp files to .o, and my cuda .cu files to .co

I want to link these so I can call the cuda stuff from my normal C++ file

Here is my linker command that Make is running:

```
g++ -I ../readers/ -I../writers -I../common/ -I /home/dcole/software/xerces-c-3.1.1/src -I /home/dcole/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ -I /usr/local/cuda/include -O3 -fPIC -fopenmp -DFIX_PAULI -DFIX_YAMA -DUSING_CUDA -o YamaguchiGPU YamaguchiMain.o YamaguchiDecomp.o cuYamaguchi.co -L/usr/lib64/ ../../lib/IDT.a ../../lib/Linux/libxerces-c.a ../../lib/Linux/libfftw3f.a -lcurl -lidn -ldl -lssl -lm -lpthread -lcuda -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
```

So I am definitly linking cuda, and cudart, but yet I get this:

```
cuYamaguchi.co: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_46_tmpxft_00003190_00000000_4_cuYamaguchi_cpp1_ii_init_gpu()':
tmpxft_00003190_00000000-1_cuYamaguchi.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
tmpxft_00003190_00000000-1_cuYamaguchi.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an absolute search path in the linker to `_libcudart.so_`. I changed the `-L` to point to just the folder, then added `-libcudart` so it would search the folder for that lib.

Answer (score 1):

The Cuda file is being linked without problems but it looks like you might have forgotten to define some necessary function (like cudaRegisterFatBinary).

Comment: So, these are functions that are part of the cuda API. My source .cu file has included cuda.h and cuda_runtime.h

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to gcc 4.7.0 or higher should fix this horrid linker issue.